# java CDI Extension with dynamic class loading

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi

The goal is to load a bunch of jar files as plugins from a remote location, initialize them inside CDI context.

Then a servlet can fire events like like so:

```
testEvent.fire(new EventTest("some message"));
```

Which the plugin will be able to observe. An example plugin will look something like this:

```
public class Plugin{
    public void respond (@Observes EventTest e){
        //does something with the even object
    }
}
```

Here is the code that supposedly loads the plugin. Taken and reworked from https://jaxenter.com/tips-for-writing-pluggable-java-ee-applications-105281.html This class sits in the same package as the servlet class. It has the necessary META-INF/services directory with the javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension file that has a single line - the fully qualified name of the extension class: main.initplugins.InitPlugins .

```
package main.initplugins;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;

import java.util.jar.JarInputStream;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;

import java.lang.ClassLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeforeBeanDiscovery;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;

public class InitPlugins implements javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension{
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("");
    private java.util.Set<Class<?>> classes;

    public void beforeBeanDiscovery(@Observes BeforeBeanDiscovery bbd, BeanManager bm){
        log.log(Level.INFO, "LOAD PLUGINS HERE");
        loadFromFiles();

        try{
            for (Class<?> cl: classes){
                final javax.enterprise.inject.spi.AnnotatedType<?> at = bm.createAnnotatedType(cl);
                bbd.addAnnotatedType(at);
                log.log(Level.INFO, "ADD ANNOTATED TYPE FOR: " + cl.getName());

            }
            log.log(Level.INFO, "ANNOTATED TYPE CREATION COMPLETE");
        } catch (Exception ex){
            log.log(Level.INFO, "FAIL TO CREATE ANNOTATED TYPE: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void loadFromFiles() {

        classes = new java.util.LinkedHashSet<Class<?>>();

        try{

            //connect to a remote location. In this case it will be a database that holds the bytes of the .jar files
            Connection dbConnection = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb?user=user&password=passwd");
            Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
            java.sql.ResultSet plugins = statement.executeQuery("select * from plugins"); //the plugins table contain 2 columns: 1) fileName as primary key, 2) longblob that hold raw byte of the jar file

            while (plugins.next()){
                JarInputStream js = new JarInputStream(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(plugins.getBytes(2))); //load them as jar files, 2 is the index for the raw byte column that holds the jar file

                JarEntry je;
                while((je = js.getNextJarEntry()) != null){
                //open each jar file, scan through file contents and find the .class files, then extract those bytes and pass them in the ClassLoader's defineClass method

                    if(!je.isDirectory() && je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
                        String className = je.getName().substring(0, je.getName().length() - 6).replace("/", ".");
                        log.log(Level.INFO, "class name is: " + className);

                        java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream classBytes = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        byte[] bytes;

                        try{
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                            int read = 0;
                            while(js.available() > 0){
                                read = js.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                                if(read > 0){
                                    classBytes.write(buffer, 0, read);
                                }
                            }
                            bytes = classBytes.toByteArray();

                            //code below taken from: https://jaxenter.com/tips-for-writing-pluggable-java-ee-applications-105281.html
                            java.security.ProtectionDomain protDomain = getClass().getProtectionDomain();
                            ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                            Method tempDefineClassMethod = null;
                            for (Method tempMethod : ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethods()){
                                if(tempMethod.getName().equals("defineClass") && tempMethod.getParameterCount() == 5){
                                    tempDefineClassMethod = tempMethod;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            final Method defineClassMethod = tempDefineClassMethod;
                            try{
                                java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction(){
                                    @Override
                                    public java.lang.Object run() throws Exception{
                                        if (!defineClassMethod.isAccessible()){
                                            defineClassMethod.setAccessible(true);
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                });
                                log.log(Level.INFO, "Attempting load class: " + className + " with lenght of: " + bytes.length);
                                defineClassMethod.invoke(cl, className, bytes, 0, bytes.length, protDomain);
                                classes.add(cl.loadClass(className));
                                log.log(Level.INFO, "Loaded class: " + je.getName());

                            } catch (Exception ex){
                                log.log(Level.INFO, "Error loading class: " + ex.getMessage());
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex){
                            log.log(Level.INFO, "Error loading bytes: " + ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex){
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Fail to get db connection or create statement in plugin ejb: ".concat(ex.getMessage()));
        } catch (Exception ex){
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Fail to get db connection or create statement in plugin ejb: ".concat(ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work for some reason. No errors are thrown at any stage. When i fire the event from the servlet, the loaded plugin doesn't pick it up. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see your log messages indicating that the class was loaded?  Also, how do you deploy your app? What container (including version)

Comment: Yes, all log messages are shown, including the ones in the @Observable method: "ADD ANNOTATED TYPE FOR: " + ... and  "ANNOTATED TYPE CREATION COMPLETE".

Using wildfly 10.1

Comment: And just wondering, what does your `beans.xml` look like? Does this happen to work when you add a scope to your `Plugin`, like `@ApplicationScoped`?

Comment: My beans.xml is in the servlet package that holds the servlet and the InitPlugins class. It's standard beans.xml with a bean-discovery-mode="all" attribute. Added @javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped to plugin, but still it won't pick up the events fired from the servlet. Also tried another server - glassfish, but there is even worse - it won't even execute the InitPlugins class with the Extension.

Comment: The event payload - `EventTest` - is it the same class/package in case of the plugin and servlet? Depending on the deployment structure it might also happen that `EventTest` would be loaded by a different class loader which could cause troubles. Verify that the same CL loads both, `EventTest` and the plugin class. Furthermore, you could try to add a bean defining annotation to the plugin classes you register as beans (a plain old `@Dependent` will do) but this is just a blind guess. Can you also verify that the beans you register can be used in some way? E.g. injected for instance.

Comment: To add on to my previous comment, you can try using a 'standard' class loader instead of TCCL. E.g. use the same CL which loaded the extension (the one you obtain via `InitPlugins.class.getClassLoader()`).

Comment: Just an update. I recreated this offline in JavaSE with the bootstrapped weld container. The code, taken as it is 1:1 works flawlessly and the plugin catches the event. I will look into the class loaders as @Siliarus suggested and make another update on the issue.

Comment: @Siliarus, voalia - the problem was in the class loader. By using the InitPlugins class loader it worked in the servlet container and in java se. Thank you very much. Please, add an answer so i can close this issue :)

Comment: @hrs answer created, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From CDI standpoint, your approach should work just fine.

**The problem here is class loading**, especially when considering any non-flat deployment (anything else than pure SE).

You chose to use TCCL, e.g. you did:

```
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
```

Which, in certain application servers/servlets, might give you a different class loader than the one that loaded the extension itself (`InitPlugin`).

Instead, you should use the same CL which loaded the extension as that is going to be the one handling CDI beans. So, just do this:

```
ClassLoader cl = InitPlugins.class.getClassLoader()
```

**NOTE:** *Be aware that you are sailing undefined waters. This behavior/fix will likely not be portable.*